# RIP, Charles Grodin

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Charles Grodin, who had a long and fruitful film career, died today.  Primarily a comedic actor, he had major roles as the villains in *King Kong* (1976) and *The Great Muppet Caper*, as well as smaller parts in *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*, *Rosemary's Baby*, *Heaven Can Wait*, and *Heart and Souls*; and many other non-genre productions.  His most famous role may have been in the action-comedy *Midnight Run*, opposite Robert De Niro.

[image: The Stars of Midnight Run]

Here he is, as I will always remember him, singing to Miss Piggy (in the greatest Busby Berkeley parody every produced).

Comment: One of my favorite roles of his was as Murray Blum in the 1993 film "Dave".

"Who does these books? If I ran my business this way, I'd be OUT of business!"

Comment: Awww, I need to re-watch Beethoven now!

Comment: @Möoz Oddly enough, I just watched *Midnight Run* about a week and a half ago, which I think made Grodin's death especially poignant.

Comment: Wow, TIL he was in 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea.

Answer (score 5):

I remember him well from HB Kid. He was a young man; Cybil S. was just out of her teens and even Eddie Albert was not that old. Time is a heck of a thing.